# How to install templ in macos. Error:- templ not found

Tags: go, echo

docs says.

1. go install github.com/a-h/templ/cmd/templ@latest [This does not work.]

what I did.
1.

```
git clone https://github.com/a-h/templ.git [in /tmp]
```

2. 

```
cd cmd/templ && go install
```

still Error.

Solution I came up with.
1.

```
alias templ=$HOME/go/bin/templ [also added in ~/.zshrc]
```

why this does not work

```
go install github.com/a-h/templ/cmd/templ@latest
```

How Can I resolve it.

Comment: What is the error you get? It works fine for me (MacOS).

Comment: If it just doesn't find `templ` after installing, it is because you need to add `$HOME/go/bin` to PATH variable. It has nothing to do with `go install` not working. If this is the case: add `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/go/bin"` to `~/.zshrc` (and remove the alias again).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`go install` worked just fine as you can see from the alias you created. It only works because the installation was successful.

Add `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/go/bin"` to your `~/.zshrc` file to add Go's default installation folder to `PATH`. That way all binaries that are installed with `go install` will be available globally.

Comment: Mine was not working because I added $HOME/go/bin/templ